# What are sufficient/necessary conditions for the triviality of a sigma algebra/Field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory

We call a $\sigma$-Algebra or $\sigma$-Field $\cal {F}$ **P**-trivial iff $\forall A \in \cal {F}: P(A) \in \{0;1\} $.

Are there other sufficient and/or necessary conditions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I guess if and only if it's generated by $P$-null sets.